# Unwind and alias used together in an OrientDB SQL query

Tags: sql, orientdb

Using OrientDB 2.2.16 and given the following data imported in a document database:

```
{
    "teams": [
        {
            "name": "McLaren F1 Team",
            "nationality": "british",
            "headquarters": {
                "city": "Woking",
                "country": "England"
            },
            "drivers": [
                {
                    "name": "Fernando Alonso",
                    "nationality": "Spanish",
                    "yearOfBirth": "1980"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Jenson Button",
                    "nationality": "British",
                    "yearOfBirth": "1980"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Scuderia Ferrari",
            "nationality": "italian",
            "headquarters": {
                "city": "Maranello",
                "country": "Italy"
            },
            "drivers": [
                {
                    "name": "Sebastian Vettel",
                    "nationality": "German",
                    "yearOfBirth": "1987"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Kimi Raikkonen",
                    "nationality": "Finnish",
                    "yearOfBirth": "1979"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Using unwind**, I want to find the query returning the names of all the drivers. To be exact, the result has to be a list of documents where each document contains the name of a driver in a property called "name".

My (not working) attempts:

**SELECT drivers.name FROM Teams unwind drivers**

It returns almost what I expect, but the name is placed under a property called "drivers".

**SELECT drivers.name AS name FROM Teams unwind drivers**

Fails totally, there's no unwind at all.

**SELECT drivers.name AS name FROM Teams unwind name**

This works, but it's kind of a bug actually because the alias applies to drivers, not name, and that's why the **unwind** works.

Answer (score 3):

A little background on how the query is elaborated:

1. `Teams` data is fetched from the storage
2. each record is filtered (no filtering in this case, because you have no WHERE condition)
3. for each source record, the engine calculates the projections and creates a new document containing the projection values bound to aliases

In your case, at this step you have two records:

query 1: the default alias for drivers.name in v 2.2 is `drivers` (in v 3.0 this will change, the default alias will be `drivers.name`)

```
|              drivers                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
| ["Fernando Alonso", "Jenson Button" ]   |
| ["Sebastian Vettel", "Kimi Raikkonen" ] |
```

query 2 and 3: in this case the alias is `name`, you are defining it explicitly

```
|              name                       |
+-----------------------------------------+
| ["Fernando Alonso", "Jenson Button" ]   |
| ["Sebastian Vettel", "Kimi Raikkonen" ] |
```

4. the UNWIND is calculated on the result of step 3. The alias of the result is the same as the previous step

Query 1 unwinds `drivers` as expected, but the alias remains `drivers`

Query 2  tries to unwind `drivers` but it doesn't find it obviously, this is why it fails

Query 3 unwinds `name` as expected

As a conclusion: **this is the expected behavior**

Comment: Even if it's designed to work that way, to me it's weird that the alias applies to drivers instead of name (the projection).